# MySQL - bad performance with simple order by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Tables (InnoDB):

- STUDENT - 400.000 lines (35.000 are inactive)
- CLASS - 40.000 lines
- CLASS_STUDENT - 460.000 lines

Query:

```
SELECT S.* 
FROM STUDENT S
JOIN CLASS_STUDENT CS ON CS.STUDENT_ID = S.STUDENT_ID 
JOIN CLASS C ON C.CLASS_ID = CS.CLASS_ID
WHERE S.ACTIVE = TRUE
GROUP BY S.STUDENT_ID --this suffices to fetch students only once
ORDER BY C.CLASS_DATE DESC --datetime field
LIMIT 0,5
```

Execution time with `ORDER BY`: 3.2297 sec

Execution time without `ORDER BY`: 0.0015 sec

3 seconds in my system is a lot of time that will result in a bad experience to my users. Isn't there any way to speedup this query with `ORDER BY`? The `LIMIT` is for pagination. I'm ordering by `CLASS_DATE` desc because I want to see in my paginated results firstly the students attending to recent classes.

**I cannot remove the joins I'm using**.

Thanks!

EDIT: `EXPLAIN` for both queries:

[image: EXPLAIN for both queries]

EDIT2: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` = 4GB and I have 16 GB in my server

Comment: Why do you need to order students by class dates?

Comment: This statement doesn't make a lot of sense. If a student takes multiple classes then they are going to appear multiple times in your resultset. Is `S.*` really what you want here? (even discounting the fact that you should **never** use `SELECT *`)

Comment: @Bulat, I want to show information about the students. I'm most interested in the ones attending the newest classes. But I want to paginate all the students nonetheless.

Comment: As Tom mentioned, same student will appear in results many times. Better design would be to order the classes first, and then load students in those classes

Comment: If you want to show each student only once you should change your order to `ORDER BY MAX(C.CLASS_DATE) DESC`.

Comment: Do you have an index for `CLASS_DATE`?

Comment: @PM77-1 index on CLASS_DATE didn't change the execution time.

Comment: @dnoeth with your suggestion the time increased to  3.9268 sec

Comment: @qxlab: But now the result is correct :-)

Comment: The order by causes all the data to be scanned, to find those that match.  The unordered search needs to find any 6 records

Comment: Post the results of `EXPLAIN`  for both queries.

Comment: Are there lots of student where `S.ACTIVE = FALSE`?

Comment: @TomH no, the students are appearing only once because I'm grouping them.

Comment: @PM77-1 let me get the EXPLAIN and attach here

Comment: @dnoeth there are 35.000 students inactive

Comment: Look in your config,what is the size of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?And what is your RAM?

Comment: @Mihai `innodb_buffer_pool_size` = 4GB and I have 16 GB in my server

Comment: Try changing it to 8 GB ,restart mysql and run the same query.Any improvement?

Comment: @Mihai minimal improvement: 2.9600 sec

Comment: The `class_date` value resulting from the `GROUP BY` operation is *indeterminate*. There is no guarantee that the latest `class_date` for a student will be used for ordering. The query can return *any* `class_date` related for a student. Other databases would throw an error with this statement. A MySQL extension to the standard allows the query to run, but we can get the query to throw an error in MySQL by setting `sql_mode` to include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Comment: Also, the order that students with the same `class_date` value is also indeterminate. MySQL is is free to return the rows for the students with the same `class_date` in any order. In terms of performance, it's the "Using filesort" operation on the large set that is consuming the time.

Answer (score 1):

If this was my project, I would only list each student once. Not multiple times, repeating the student for each row in the enrollment (`CLASS_STUDENT`) table.

I would seriously consider denormalizing the database implementation, by adding  a derived column to the `STUDENT` table, e.g.

```
 ALTER TABLE STUDENT ADD latest_class_date DATE DEFAULT NULL;
```

And populate that column:

```
 UPDATE STUDENT t
   LEFT
   JOIN ( SELECT cs.student_id
               , MAX(c.class_date) AS latest_class_date
            FROM CLASS_STUDENT cs
            JOIN CLASS c
              ON c.class_id = cs.class_id
           GROUP BY cs.student_id
        ) s
     ON t.student_id = s.student_id   
    SET t.latest_class_date = s.latest_class_date
```

With that new column added, I could create an appropriate index, eg.

```
... ON STUDENT (active, latest_class_date, student_id)
```

Then my query is much simpler:

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM student s
 WHERE s.active = 1
 ORDER BY s.active DESC, s.latest_class_date DESC, student_id DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

I'd include the `student_id` in the `ORDER BY` to make the result deterministic. (Without that, MySQL is free to return any rows with the same `latest_class_date` in any order.)

I'd also implement pagination a little more efficiently, retaining the values from the last previously retrieved row, and supplying those values in the query. To get the "next 5 rows":

---

(**EDIT**: The query pattern for pagination in the original was glaringly wrong. This has been corrected, both here and in the last query in the followup.)

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM student s
 WHERE s.active = 1
   AND s.latest_class_date <= ?
   AND (s.latest_class_date < ? OR s.student_id < ? )
 ORDER BY s.active DESC, s.latest_class_date DESC, student_id DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

The contents of the new `latest_class_date` column will need to be maintained. A couple of choices there.

If I can live with a period of time that the contents of that column might be out of sync, then

- schedule execution of the update statement to periodically refresh the contents of that column.

If I have a requirement to keep the contents of that column synchronized, then either:

- modify the application that stewards the student, class and student_class tables to ensure the `latest_class_date` columns is populated whenever rows are added/changed/removed from `CLASS` and `STUDENT_CLASS` tables, or
- add triggers on the tables to keep that column populated

  - `BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE` triggers on `STUDENT`
  - `AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` triggers on `CLASS_STUDENT`
  - `AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/AFTER DELETE` triggers on `CLASS`

(I need to remember that triggers are not fired by foreign key actions. For example, if rows are deleted from `CLASS_STUDENT` as the result of a CASCADE action of a FOREIGN KEY when a row in deleted from `CLASS`, then only the triggers for the `CLASS` table will be fired. That means I'll have to handle the required actions in the delete trigger on the `CLASS` table.)

---

**FOLLOWUP**

If you "need all the joins" because of other information in those tables you "might need one day", the suggestion I made above isn't going to help much. In terms of performance, dollars to donuts it's the "Using filesort" operation on a huge set that is eating your lunch. Adding joins to the query I suggested isn't going to avoid that "Using filesort" operation.

If there's reasonable performance on the query I suggested, then we might be able to make use of that query as an inline view, to limit the number of rows returned, before we do the joins.

But before we do that, we have to first address the duplicated student rows returned when there are multiple rows in the enrollment (`CLASS_STUDENT`) table. Do we want the same student returned multiple times? Or do we want to return the student row multiple times, once for each row in `CLASS_STUDENT` for a class wit the same `class_date`. Or, do we want to return the student row just once, with information from just *one* `CLASS`? If we are returning multiple rows for a student, is the intent to list five students per page, or to list five student_class per page?

Assuming "pagination" of five rows per page, are we expecting a resultset like this?

rows 1 thru 5

```
student    class   class_date
-------    -----   ---------- 
Sam        phys    2016-02-12
Sam        calc    2016-02-12
Mary       lit     2016-02-12
Mahatma    art     2016-02-12
Paul       music   2016-02-11
```

rows 6 thru 10

```
Paul       engl    2016-02-11
Sam        art     2016-02-10
...
```

The query we write is going to be informed by the specification.

We can write a myriad possible queries. But without a specification, every one of those queries is just a guess. Without knowing what resultset we want returned (under a variety of possible conditions), we have no way of verifying that a query we write is correct.

---

I looked at your query again, and notice that you do have a `GROUP BY student_id`. (We're going to assume that `student_id` is unique in the `students` table.)

If there are multiple rows in the `CLASS_STUDENT` table for a student, and the `CLASS` rows that those are related to have different value for `class_date`, the value of `class_date` returned in the original query is *indeterminate*. MySQL is free to choose any of the possible `class_date` values.  (It's not just the `class_date` column... the values from the rows from `CLASS` and `CLASS_STUDENT` are indeterminate.)

With the original query, there is no guarantee that students with the "latest" class_date are going to be listed before other students. For example, with this set:

```
student   class_date
-------   ----------
Sam       2016-02-22 
Sam       2015-07-17
Paul      2016-01-11
```

The query above could order the rows with `Sam` before `Paul`, or with `Sam` after `Paul`. Either result is valid with the original query. And you aren't guaranteed that every time you run the query the result will be the same. The result is *indeterminate*.

Other databases would throw an error with the original query, along the lines of "non-aggregate in SELECT list not appearing in GROUP BY clause". A MySQL specific extension allows the query to execute. It's possible to get MySQL to behave the same way as other databases, and throwing an error, by including `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in the `sql_mode`.

---

```
SELECT d.*
  FROM ( SELECT s.student_id
              , s.latest_class_date
           FROM student s
          WHERE s.active = 1
            AND s.latest_class_date <= ? 
            AND ( s.latest_class_date < ? OR s.student_id < ? )
          ORDER BY s.active DESC, s.latest_class_date DESC, student_id DESC
          LIMIT 5
       ) r
  JOIN student d
    ON d.student_id = r.student_id
  JOIN class_student e
    ON e.student_id = d.student_id
  JOIN class c
    ON c.class_id = e.class_id
   AND c.class_date = r.latest_class_date
 GROUP BY d.student_id
```

Comment: Thanks. I have thought about denormalizing it as a last resource.. but I guess you are right, it's the best alternative for me, it seems

Comment: I actually need all the joins I used in my question. There are other information there that I might need one day. And keeping the joins, even with your suggested index, the time increased to 7 seconds.

Comment: The original query was only returning rows from the `STUDENT` table, so that's what I addressed. I also purposely avoiding returning duplicate row from the `STUDENT` table. If you have to do the "join" to the other two tables, then MySQL is going to to perform a "Using filesort" operation to order the rows. And dollars to donuts, it's that operation that eating your lunch as far as performance. Using the approach in the query I posted, you could whittle down the "next five rows" in an inline view query, and then join that to the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter before the join to student:

```
SELECT S.* 
FROM STUDENT S
JOIN 
 ( select CS.STUDENT_ID, MAX(C.CLASS_DATE) AS maxDate
   from CLASS_STUDENT CS 
   JOIN CLASS C ON C.CLASS_ID = CS.CLASS_ID
   GROUP BY CS.STUDENT_ID
   ORDER BY maxDate DESC
    -- this might include non-active students
    -- but hopefully returns at least 5 students with S.ACTIVE = TRUE
   LIMIT 0,10
 ) dt
ON dt.STUDENT_ID = S.STUDENT_ID 
WHERE S.ACTIVE = TRUE
ORDER BY dt.maxDate DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

If there are lots of inactive students (35.000 out of 400.000) you might need to increase the inner LIMIT, but on the other hand inactive students will probably not attend the most recent classes :-)

Comment: Actually inactive usually are the ones still being accepted or not into the classes. Let me think about your suggestion.

Comment: I ust noticed that you wrote *The LIMIT is for pagination*, so this approach will not work.